# Using the Leibniz rule to compute the nth derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis

I need to use the Leibniz Formula: $(fg)^n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose {k}}f^{n-k}(x)g^k(x)$, to compute the nth derivative in the following formula 
$T_n(x)=\dfrac{(-1)^n(1-x^2)^{1/2}}{(2n-1)!!}\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}[(1-x^2)^{n-1/2}]$.

Any suggestions I would appreciate.

Comment: *Must* we use Leibniz's formula? Or may we apply something else?

Answer (score 0):

You may notice a striking similarity with Rodrigues formula for [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials):
$$ P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n n!}\cdot\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n. $$
Additionally, by letting $x=\cos\theta$ we have $dx = -\sin(\theta) d\theta $ and $\frac{d}{dx}=-\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\cdot\frac{d}{d\theta}$, so

$$ T_n(\cos\theta) = \frac{(-1)^n \sin(\theta)}{(2n-1)!!}\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\cdot\frac{d}{d\theta}\right)^n\left(\sin\theta\right)^{2n-1} $$
and 
$$ T_{n+2}(\cos\theta) = 2(\cos\theta)\, T_{n+1}(\cos\theta)-T_n(\cos\theta) $$
can be easily proved by induction. Since $T_1(x)=x$ and $T_2(x)=2x^2-1$, your Rodrigues-like formula exactly defines the [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is known that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n} \bigl[\bigl(1-x^2\bigr)^{n-1/2}\bigr]
=\frac{n!(2n-1)!!}{(2x)^n}\bigl(1-x^2\bigr)^{n-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{k}{n-k} \frac{2^k}{k![2(n-k)-1]!!}\biggl(\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\biggr)^k
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation}\label{Rodrigues-expl-T}
T_n(x)=x^n\sum_{\ell=0}^{\lfloor{n}/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2\ell}\biggl(1-\frac1{x^2}\biggr)^\ell
=x^n\sum_{\ell=0}^{n}\binom{n}{2\ell}\biggl(1-\frac1{x^2}\biggr)^\ell.
\end{equation}

References

1. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, and Dongkyu Lim, *Notes on explicit and inversion formulas for the Chebyshev polynomials of the first two kinds*, Miskolc Mathematical Notes **20** (2019), no. 2, 1129--1137; available online at https://doi.org/10.18514/MMN.2019.2976.